# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_I f(x)\cos nx\ \mathrm{d}m(x)=0$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, limits

> On $\mathbb R$, let $I$ be a finite interval. If $f$ is integrable on $I$, prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_I f(x)\cos nx\ \mathrm{d}m(x)=0.$$

I tried the substitution $nx=u$ but the integral became much worse looking to me... If anyone could help I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This result is known as [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).