# Let $f$ be a Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb R$. Prove that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\cos x)^nf(x)dx=0 $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

> Let $f$ be a Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb R$. Prove that
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\cos x)^nf(x)dx=0 $$

---

My attempt:

Firstly, I know the statement is true when the integrand is $\cos(nx)f(x)$ which is implied by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. (See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/626290/497335).)

Now I want to apply the same method, i.e., using simple functions to deduce the limit of the integral of $(\cos x)^n$ over any interval is zero. However, I think there is not a nice formula for the integral of $(\cos x)^n$. Though we know the recurrence formula: $$\int\cos^n x \ dx = \frac{1}n \cos^{n-1}x \sin x + \frac{n-1}{n}\int\cos^{n-2} x \ dx,$$ indeed, this can lead us to the conclusion by noticing the fact that the first term above on the RHS tends to zero as $n\to\infty$ and also $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}=0.$$

I think this should not be the best way for us to deal with this kind of problems since this relies on the recurrence formula of $\int\cos^n x dx$. Can someone provide other approaches? Thank you.

Comment: $\cos^n{x} \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere. So use the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @Mindlack There it is! I didn't aware of the fact that $\cos ^n x\to 0$ a.e. Thank you!

Comment: If you know what the dominated convergence theorem is, you should certainly know that $\cos^n x \to 0$ a.e.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the dominated convergence theorem.

Consider $g_{n}(x) = (cos(x))^{n}f(x)$ measurable. Then $|g_{n}(x)| = |(cos(x))^{n}f(x)| = |(cos(x))^{n}||f(x)| = |cos(x)|^{n}|f(x)| \leqslant |f(x)|$. We have that |f| is integrable because f is integrable.
Thus,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\cos x)^nf(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty}(\cos x)^nf(x)dx$$

Now, since $\lim_{n \to \infty}(cos(x))^{n}f(x) = 0$, because $\lim_{n \to \infty}(cos(x))^{n} = 0$ a. e, we have

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\cos x)^nf(x)dx = 0$$

Comment: $\cos(x)^n\to 0$ does not hold for **all** $x\in\Bbb R$, but only for **almost all** $x\in\Bbb R$. This is enough, though.

Comment: @MarsPlastic You're right. Thank you!